# Shared volume between Jobs ~ Gitlab Shared Runners

Tags: django, docker, gitlab, runner

I am running a Gitlab pipeline on a Django + Postgres project and I am trying to build and then run my tests inside my gitlab pipeline.

I am using a custom docker image in order to use `docker-compose` in my pipeline.

I have 2 seperate jobs : `build` and `test` but the problem is by default jobs environments are not shared, so after my first build job I can't simple run my test with

```py
  docker-compose exec -it app python manage.py run test
```

How can I achieve this without having to relauch a build in my second job for my tests ?

Comment: You need to buid the docker image and push it to the registry to use on the next step.

Comment: Did you check artifacts or caching keyword ? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/